# Nokia32/RCMM IR decoding issues

Tags: ir, arduino-pro-micro

I am trying to decode the IR signals from a remote. I'm using an Arduino Pro Micro, and a TSOP38238 IR receiver.

I found out that the remote uses the Nokia32(RCMM) protocol, and I have been able to partially decode it using cyborg5/IRLib (specifically this one: [rcmm.ino](https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib/blob/master/examples/rcmm/rcmm.ino)). I tweaked the values of the example using the LIRC file corresponding to my remote, mainly the absolute error tolerance ([Freebox_V5.lircd.conf](http://sourceforge.net/p/lirc-remotes/code/ci/master/tree/remotes/free/Freebox_V5.lircd.conf)).

Compared to other remotes I tried (with different protocols) the RCMM algorithm doesn't manage to decode the signal every time. Around 40% of the time when I press a button I got an "Unknown type received" output from the decoder.

The following is three outputs (for the same button) of the algorithm for a successful decoding and below two other outputs corresponding to two failures. Could anyone tell me what could be done to increase the success of the decoding algorithm?

### **Successful**

```
Decoded RCMM: Value:2400A601 (32 bits)
Raw samples(36): Gap:63264
  Head: m410  s290
0:m160 s290 1:m160 s590      2:m210 s390    3:m210 s240      
4:m210 s240 5:m210 s240      6:m210 s240    7:m210 s240      
8:m210 s540 9:m210 s590      10:m210 s390   11:m210 s590         
12:m160 s290    13:m160 s290         14:m160 s240   15:m210 s440         

16:m160
Extent=9810
Mark  min:160    max:210
Space min:240    max:590
```

### **Failure 1**

```
Unknown type received. Ignoring.
Decoded Unknown(0): Value:0 (0 bits)
Raw samples(36): Gap:3148
  Head: m410  s290
0:m160 s240 1:m210 s590      2:m210 s390    3:m210 s240      
4:m210 s240 5:m210 s240      6:m160 s290    7:m160 s290      
8:m160 s590 9:m210 s590      10:m160 s440   11:m210 s590         
12:m160 s240    13:m210 s240         14:m210 s240   15:m210 s390         

16:m210
Extent=9810
Mark  min:160    max:210
Space min:240    max:590
```

### **Failure 2**

```
Unknown type received. Ignoring.
Decoded Unknown(0): Value:0 (0 bits)
Raw samples(32): Gap:27904
  Head: m410  s290
0:m160 s290 1:m160 s590      2:m160 s490    3:m160 s240      
4:m210 s240 5:m160 s290      6:m160 s290    7:m160 s290      
8:m160 s290 9:m160 s590      10:m160 s490   11:m160 s590         
12:m160 s1190   13:m160 s440         14:m160
Extent=9460
Mark  min:160    max:210
Space min:240    max:1190
```

Comment: Are all three of those for the same button?

Comment: yes, my bad I edited the text to be more clear

Comment: I can see where the third one went wrong (not why, only where so far), but just correlating them all together at the moment in a spreadsheet. Manually decoding :)

Comment: the timings are left unchanged from the original file (https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib/blob/master/examples/rcmm/rcmm.ino line 35). The tolerance line 60 is set to 100.

Comment: The problem is very much with the timing. I don't yet know whether that is the reception timing or the transmission timing, but there are some big errors in the numbers.

Comment: Hmmm... Manually decoding the values - the second one should have worked (better than the first one actually). The third is a complete failure of course.

Comment: Incidentally, from those figures, a tolerance of 75 should be good to use.

Comment: Sorry not to have been able to answer earlier. Here is the output of 10 clicks on one button with a tolerance of 75 : http://pastebin.com/jrZaDQty. What is quite wierd is the decoding value when there is a success (it's either 2400A601 or 24002601). I'm a bit lost ...

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to provide a complete answer yet but my research so far into a similar quest to use a similar remote can at least answer why you are getting two values for the same button on the remote. This is by design: the Nokia-32 RCMM protocol of this remote uses toggling codes that flip between one value and another on alternating presses of the same button.

My quest and the challenges of decoding this remote are documented in this thread: https://github.com/bengtmartensson/harctoolboxbundle/issues/97 where I discover that my IR remote uses Nokia 32 protocol but with mark and space timings slightly different from what most Arduino libraries are programmed for requiring a tweak to the signal in order to enable other libraries to decode it successfully.

Further information here: http://www.avsforum.com/forum/93-remote-control-area/1517341-theater-master-mx-500-remote-won-t-learn-bell-fibe-remote-any-help.html#post24345872 where we learn:

> it is different from most IR signals, because it has 4 different off durations, denoting zero, one, two , or three, while traditionally IR protocols have used just two off durations signifying zero or one.

Comment: Could you please highlight the most important parts of the websites you've linked? If at one point those links break this answer will be unfortunately useless and we'd like to avoid that.

Comment: done... an upvote would be encouraging